# C++ Simplify loop over map and extending/overwriting of vector

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, stdvector, stdmap

Given

- `std::vector<int> vec1` of size `s_vec` and capacity `c`.
- `std::vector<int> vec2`.
- `std::map<int, int> m` of size `s_m >= s_vec`.
- `std::unordered_set<int> flags`.
- `bool flag = False`

I want to copy as many values of `m` (in order) into `vec1` (overwriting previous values) without exceeding the capacity `c`. If any values remain I want to push those values to the end of `vec2`. For each of these, values I want to check if they are in `flags`. If they are, I'd like to set `flag` to true.

This is how I currently, achieve this:

```
  int i = 0;
  for (auto const& e : m) {
    if(i < c) {
      if(i == vec1.size()) {
        vec1.push_back(e.second);
      } else {
        vec1.at(i) = e.second;
      }
    } else {
      vec2.push_back(e.second);
      if(flags.count(e.second)){
        flag = true;
      }
    }
  }
```

I am new to C++ coming from python and R. Therefore, I assume that this can be simplified quite a bit (with iterators?). What can I do to improve the code here?

Comment: @NathanOliver Is that really the case? I believe the code above is overwriting `vec1` first and then switches over to `push_back(...)` (note the test for `i == vec1.size()`).

Comment: Woops, missed that extra branch.

Comment: You should be looking at the algorithm functions such as `std::copy` and `std::transform`. -- *I am new to C++ coming from python and R. Therefore, I assume* -- And stating that, hopefully you are not using python and R as models in writing C++ code.

Comment: `std::unordered_map<int>` > you are missing a template parameter here. Or is it a `std::unordered_set<int>`? Why not include the declarations with the code?

Comment: To be honest, even your current code is overly complex.  Why not compute how many you will need to copy to vec1 and vec2 first before you enter the loop, and thus eliminate all of the logic comparing `i` to `vec1.size()`, `vec2.size()`, etc?  All of that information is available to you without the complexity.  Once you do that, then it is probably two calls to `std::transform` or similar algorithm function.

Comment: @Nelfeal You are right! It should be a set. I fixed it in the question. Thanks for pointing out the typo.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for the comments. I'll try to implement your ideas (with the snippets provided by @Nelfeal) and report back.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie A shame there is no `std::transform_n`. Doing `m.begin() + c` isn't great. Or is there an alternative I'm not seeing?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I added an answer based on your comment. It would be helpful to get some feedback on the code.

Answer (score 1):

Your code must increment i at the end of each loop for it to work.

If you can use c++20 and its ranges, I would probably rewrite it completely, to something like:

```
using namespace std::views; // for simplicity here
    
std::ranges::copy(m | take(c) | values, vec1.begin());
std::ranges::copy(m | drop(c) | values, std::back_inserter(vec2));
flag = std::ranges::any_of(vec2, [&flags](int i){return flags.contains(i);});
```

The beauty of this, is that it matches your requirements much better.

- The first lines does: "*I want to copy as many values of m (in order) into vec1 (overwriting previous values) without exceeding the capacity c.*"
- The second line does: "*If any values remain I want to push those values to the end of vec2.*"
- The third line does: "*For each of these, values I want to check if they are in flags. If they are, I'd like to set flag to true.*"

Comment: Thanks really much for your answer! It looks great. Unfortunately, I am using C++ 11.

Comment: @s1624210 The [boost libraries](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html) have a precursor to what was standardised into C++20, which would be `copy(m | sliced(0, c) | map_values, vec1.begin()); copy(m | sliced(c, size(m)-1) | map_values, std::back_inserter(vec2)); flag = any_of(vec2, [&flags](int i){return flags.contains(i);});`

Answer (score 1):

Building on the comments of @PaulMcKenzie and the answers provided by @Nelfeal and @cptFracassa, this is what I ended up with.

```
size_t new_size = std::min(vec1.capacity(), m.size());
vec1.resize(new_size);

std::transform(m.begin(),
               std::next(m.begin(), new_size),
               vec1.begin(),
               [](std::pair<int, int> p) { return p.second; });
std::transform(std::next(m.begin(), new_size),
               m.end(),
               std::back_inserter(vec2),
               [&flags, &flag](std::pair<int, int> p) { 
                   if(flags.count(p.second)) {
                       flag = true;
                   }
                   return p.second;
               });
```

Comment: `std::transform(m.begin(), std::next(m.begin(), new_size),` -- Probably could have been: `std::transform(m.begin(), m.begin() + new_size,`.  Then `std::transform(m.begin() + new_size, m.end(),...)`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I started off with this. However, I get the following error `no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘std::map::iterator’ {aka ‘std::_Rb_tree_iterator >’} and ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’}`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Not for maps, that will not work.

Comment: ok, yes there is no `+` for map iterators.

Comment: @s1624210 Capture 'flags' by reference in the lambda, if not you're making an unnecessary copy of it.

Comment: @cptFracassa Thanks! I fixed it in my code but will keep the answer as is to serve as an example for future readers (in conjunction with your comment).

Comment: `[](std::pair<int, int> p)` -- Also, this should be passed by const reference: `[](const std::pair<int, int>& p)`.  Right now the key and value are `int`, but if they are a more complex type in the future, passing the pair by value would become an issue.

Comment: @s1624210 One more thing: I would probably replace the `if` with `flag |= flags.count(p.second);` I think that's clearer.

Comment: @cptFracassa I don't find bitwise operations to be clearer than a conditional assignment. If anything, I'd write `flag = flag || flags.count(p.second);` instead.

Comment: "will keep the answer as is to serve as an example for future readers (in conjunction with your comment)" Probably a bad idea, don't expect future readers to read comments. In the best case this will just generate more comments with the same content. In the worst case people will copy the inefficient version and it will appear in some code base.

Comment: @paleonix I see you point and have fixed the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In the first part, instead of doing either `push_back` or assignment to `at`, you can just `clear` the vector and `push_back` everything. `clear` does not change the `capacity`.

Your loop is doing two different things, one after the other (and by the way, I assume you forgot to increment `i`). You should split it into two loops.

With all that, your code becomes:

```
vec1.clear();
auto it = m.begin();
for (int i = 0; i < c; ++i) {
    vec1.push_back(it->second);
    ++it;
}
while (it != m.end()) {
    vec2.push_back(it->second);
    if(flags.count(it->second)){
        flag = true;
    }
    ++it;
}
```

At this point, you can also use standard algorithms (`std::copy`, `std::transform` as mentioned in the comments).

Comment: I added an example based on `std::transform` below. Please let me know what you think .